# Azure DevOps - how do I report on test case iterations (parameters)

Tags: azure, testing, parameters, reporting, visibility

Our team are using parameters in test cases to reflect multiple iterations of tests using different data sets.

For example - my test suite contains 4 tests.

Test A - contains 23 iterations.
Test B - contains 8 iterations.
Test C - contains 8 iterations.
Test D - contains 23 iterations.

Test results show there are 4 test cases not executed, but in reality, there are 62 test iterations to execute.

I haven't been able to identify a way to easily see this information, without drilling down into each test case. This is counter productive and there must be a simpler way to get an overview of the execution effort - rather than show a report with 4 tests not run?

Any assistance you could provide to help me gain simple, clear visibility would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

I tried:

- adding additional columns.
- checking different views and graphs.

Nothing seems to reflect the number of iterations contained in test cases - presented in an easy overview / report.